# Usage of "a bit"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs

Sentence is "Shy a bit, Cutie."
Is it a good sentence? I just have doubts.
I wanna say to "Cutie" to feel shy a little bit.

Comment: The above would usually be interpreted as a question about the demeanor of "Cutie".

Comment: Ordering someone to feel shy doesn't make sense. It's like instructing someone to feel tired.

Comment: However you could say "Act a bit shy". The title mentions "a bit" -- what is your question about that phrase? It simply means ["somewhat", or "a little"](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/a_bit).

Comment: 'She is a little shy' is an acceptable sentence, but not an acceptable answer on ELU.

Comment: I've already stated that 'I wanna say to "Cutie" to feel shy a little bit.' is nonsense.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

"Shy a bit" is not a correct usage for 'feeling shy'. If you do want to tell Cutie to feel a bit shy, the only way is to say (as you yourself suggested), "feel a bit shy, Cutie" or "feel a little shy, Cutie", but it is certainly peculiar to instruct somebody to 'feel shy', as the learned member said. It might of course make sense, depending on your context.

Comment: Anonymous, nothing about the question or examples makes sense.

*Shy a bit, Cutie* could mean *That is/you are short a bit…* as, we needed 12 but you found only 11

*feel shy a little bit* suggests a completely different meaning: *Please feel a little bit shy…* not ungrammatical but no native speaker would ever say it.

*You should feel shy (ie, ashamed) about that* would make sense but comparing the two would be hugely stretching a point.

*… she'll shy because of my action* makes no sense.

*That sentence is ‘attached’ to my action* makes no sense

What is your language, please?